# QGraphicsScene Mouse Event

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm working with QGraphicsScene class. How can I detect the mouse leaving from the QGraphicsScene ? Is there any internal function for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect the release event you must override the [`mouseReleaseEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#mouseReleaseEvent) method:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print(event.scenePos())
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = GraphicsScene()
    w = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Update:

The QGraphicsScene itself is not an element that allows to detect when you leave it since this can be part of several QGraphicsView, what you must do is detect when you leave the QGraphicsView override the [`leaveEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent) method:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print("enter")
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print("leave")
        super().leaveEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    w = GraphicsView(scene)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I want to detect signal without pressing at QGraphicsScene. Is there any other option?